# What is Mac OSX's "thor" command

Tags: macos

I was freely browsing to my /usr/local/bin/ folder and I wanted to test my brand new `tree --noreport -fp` command, and suddenly, I saw a program nammed `thor` so I wanted to know more about it. 
However it turns out that no one know about it on Google and I can't found any info on it. So I tried to run it and it look like a packet manager:

```
sam1902$ thor -h
Commands:
  thor help [COMMAND]  # Describe available commands or one specific command
  thor install NAME    # Install an optionally named Thor file into your system commands
  thor installed       # List the installed Thor modules and commands
  thor list [SEARCH]   # List the available thor commands (--substring means .*SEARCH)
  thor uninstall NAME  # Uninstall a named Thor module
  thor update NAME     # Update a Thor file from its original location
  thor version         # Show Thor version

sam1902$ thor version
Thor 0.19.1
sam1902$ thor installed
No Thor commands available
```

So I would like to know, by pure curiosity, if someone already heard about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this?

*"Thor is a toolkit for building powerful command-line interfaces."*

https://github.com/erikhuda/thor

The latest GitHub release is 0.19.1

More: http://whatisthor.com/

Comment: No sry, I don't think that it's the same since the one you are talking about is a ruby tookit but mine is a standalone command that don't seems to be related to ruby

Comment: @SamuelPrevost It is exactly this. See e.g. https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/465 which shows the same help text that you have. Ruby toolkits are often standalone commands.

Comment: @A.Grandt Ok, thanks for answer I accepted your answer ^^